# Using REST for Google Drive using Oauth2

Tags: javascript, oauth-2.0, google-drive-api

I am trying to get a list of files from my google drive. I have authenticated myself using Oauth2 and now I am trying to get my file list by using GET method of oauth2: "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files".

My js code is as follows:

```
var gdrive = {}
gdrive.currentgdrivepageID = null;
gdrive.log = function(_data){
    console.log("Logging gdrive response data : ");
    console.log(_data);
}

gdrive.init = function(){
    //init oauth
    OAuth.initialize('xD#################F8')
        OAuth.popup('google_drive').done(function(result) {
        console.log(result);
        gdrive.app=result;

    })
    .fail(function (err) {
        //handle error with err
        console.log(err);

      });
}


gdrive.getFiles = function(){
    var html='';
    var fileTypeList=[];

    gdrive.app.get("v2/files?key="+gdrive.app.access_token).then(function(resp){
        console.log(resp);

        window.alert('Success');


    });
}


$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on("click","#gdrive-init", function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        gdrive.init();
    })
    .on("click", "#files", function(){
        gdrive.getFiles();
    })

})
```

I am getting a "404 (Not Found)" error. Is my call correct?

```
gdrive.app.get("v2/files?key="+gdrive.app.access_token).then(function(resp){}
```

I had done similar get requests in facebook and twitter and it worked! But in Google, I am having problems. How can I make this work? As I am a newbie, I have done so much research in Google's REST api, viewed numerous gits and watched youtube videos to solve this; still I am on the same level! Please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@abhisekG, I think your call is incorrect. Have you tried checking [Drive Rest API JavaScript Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/web/quickstart/js), this will help you check and explore the API and it's functionalities.

This is sample javascript application in the documentation that can help you understand how Google Drive's Rest API works.

```
      /**
       * Load Drive API client library.
       */
      function loadDriveApi() {
        gapi.client.load('drive', 'v2', listFiles);
      }



      /**
       * Print files.
       */
      function listFiles() {
        var request = gapi.client.drive.files.list({
            'maxResults': 10
          });

          request.execute(function(resp) {
            appendPre('Files:');
            var files = resp.items;
            if (files && files.length > 0) {
              for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
                var file = files[i];
                appendPre(file.title + ' (' + file.id + ')');
              }
            } else {
              appendPre('No files found.');
            }
          });
      }
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I have started using the google api to make API calls for google.